# Can you give a "living" to someone?

Tags: word-usage

If you interact with someone, and give someone good experiences and a good life, in general, would it be correct to say:

"Person A gave a good living to person B."

Comment: Perhaps, although I would probably use the verb "provide" instead of "give". It is certainly OK to say, for example, "Company X provides a good standard of living for its employees." However, I think that this question may work better on English Language Learners, because it is asking about basic usage of a common word.

Comment: If you give someone 'a living' you give them either the money they need to live, or a job that does that.

Comment: No, it's flat out wrong. I make a good living=I earn a good salary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, "a living" in this usage is pretty much limited to monetary income. As in "I don't really care for my job but it is at least a living."

Answer (score 2):

If you read some classics from the UK you'll see another meaning of *living* -- it's kind of a job for life in the church.  At least that's what I figured out from the context.  I suppose a comprehensive UK dictionary would include that meaning.

Your phrase "good life" can be useful.  Example: (widow reflecting on her late husband's character) *He was a bit of a skirt chaser when he was younger, but he settled down after 40 and I have to say he gave me a good life.*  Except that isn't limited to the financial aspect. For pure finances, you could say, *He worked hard and supported me well all these years.*

Comment: Yes, in old-fashioned usage the _living_ was the post of vicar of the parish, often appointed by the local landowner. Nowadays clergy appointments are made by the church authorities, and clergy commonly move from one kind of parish to another as their career progresses.